# Exeption virtual patch ascx

Tags: c#, asp.net, ascx

its my code

```
protected void SendButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UserControl uc = new UserControl();
        bool Ok = false;
        string userControl = "";
        string ID = "0";
        ID = UCid.Text;
        if(ID == "1")
        {
            userControl = Server.MapPath(@"~\UCtest_one.ascx");
            Ok = true;
        }
        else if (ID == "2")
        {
            userControl = Server.MapPath(@"~\UCtest_two.ascx");
            Ok = true;
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("Eror!!! Enter only 1 or 2");
            Ok = false;
        }

        if (Ok)
        {
         //here
     uc = LoadControl(userControl) as UserControl;
            ViewUC.Controls.Add(uc);
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("Eror!!!");
        }
    }
```

> System.Web.HttpException
>         HResult=0x80004005
>    Message='.../UCtest_one.ascx'
>   is a physical path, but a virtual path was expected.
>   Source=ASCXruntime   StackTrace:    at
>   ASCXruntime.Default.SendButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
>   ...\Default.aspx.cs:line
>   43

Comment: You don't need the server.mappath just give it the virtual path (~\...)

Answer (score 0):

its true`

```
protected void SendButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UserControl uc = new UserControl();
    bool Ok = false;
    string userControl = "";
    string ID = "0";
    ID = UCid.Text;
    if(ID == "1")
    {
        userControl = MapPath(@"~\UCtest_one.ascx");
        Ok = true;
    }
    else if (ID == "2")
    {
        userControl = MapPath(@"~\UCtest_two.ascx");
        Ok = true;
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("Eror!!! Enter only 1 or 2");
        Ok = false;
    }

    if (Ok)
    {

 uc = LoadControl(userControl) as UserControl;
        ViewUC.Controls.Add(uc);
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("Eror!!!");
    }
}
```